# swift can catch fatal error?

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, fatal-error

I am trying to use Swift 2.0 try-catch.

I originally had the following code

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    var obj : Object?;
    Hi( obj );
}
```

But it procdues an error

```
func Hi( open : Open? ) -> Open?
{
    open!.Hi(); <-- here is error point. Fatal error !
    print( "OK" );

    return open;
}
```

Therefore I changed the code in viewDidLoad() to:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    try
    {
        var obj : Object?;
        Hi( obj );
    }
    catch
    {
        print( "bug !!!" ); <- I want to this !!!
    }
}
```

But it does not work !!!

I guess swift's try-catch is different than in C, C#.

How can I catch the fatal error ?

Might the following be a proper swift way?

```
func Hi( open : Open? ) -> Open?
{
    if let op = open
    {
        op.Hi();
        print( "OK" );

        return open;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just read all of this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 7):

You are not supposed to catch fatalerror. It indicates a programming error. You don't catch programming errors, you fix your code. The crash is intentional and it is intentional that you cannot stop it.

Something involving the keywords try, catch and throw is available in Swift 2, but that is nothing like C++ exceptions that you seem to be thinking about.

Comment: That's such a shame ! Thanks your answer ^^a

Comment: "Nothing like C++ exceptions"? I... take exception to that. It's pretty much the same idea, right?

Comment: "You don't catch programming errors, you fix your code." is terrible, apps out in the wild with 1000s of users have lots of permutations of code and data that you cannot have foreseen and tested all of in advance. For the time being we have to use Objective-C so you can catch exceptions, log them and let the app fail gracefully instead of just crashing like a Swift app.

Comment: There are many scenarios where catching a fatal error is completely reasonable. For example: decoding a complex binary data received from server with tons of possible index out of range errors. Checking them manually would make the code much harder to read.

Comment: What if we implement 3rd party library into the project, and unfortunately, if a runtime error occurs inside the library and doesn't throw any exceptions, then how to handle the exception gracefully? Should we allow the app crashes and wait until the library updated? Ideally, Swift error handling has a very nice concept, but we still need try catch statement as we used in objective-c.

Comment: Totally agree with @MartinBelcher-AtWrk. Another thing I can add to his words: there are cases when you don't have proper API in iOS SDK to avoid the fatal errors - the only choice you have is either crash or catch it. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849500/this-nspersistentstorecoordinator-has-no-persistent-stores-device-locked-it-c

Comment: **I would down-vote, but it's not your fault, Swift just immature** (but simpler than ObjC syntax, so we should avoid **`!`** till they make it catchable, instead of switching to ObjC). May seem like no big deal now, but once you develop with extension API, any fatal-error causes crash before you can attach debugger (and does not log with `os_log(...)` function).

Comment: Well it is impossible then to prevent an app crash if using some 3rd party library (not maintained anymore). That is quite annoying.

Comment: How to test that application raises fatal error correctly? In other words if fatal error should be raised intentionally and handled intentionally?

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch `fatalError` It actually crash your application with an error message, relevant file and the line number. By reading the `fatalError` you'll be able to get more details about the crash. We can intentionally use them to catch issues in development as well. Please read [this article](https://medium.com/@katramesh91/how-to-use-swift-fatalerror-to-prevent-issues-on-production-3ef42b9538ee) to learn more about the `fatalError`

Answer (score -2):

When you're calling `Hi()` like this: `open!.Hi();`, your program can crash if `open` is nil.

`open` is a parameter, and the value that is passed as that parameter is defined on the call site as such: `var obj : Object?;`. You're defining a new variable named `obj` with type `Object?`, but you're not assigning it a value. This means that `obj` will be nil and therefore `open` will be nil and this leads to `open!.Hi()` crashing.

To solve it, make sure to assign a value to the parameter of `Hi`. It might be better to make the parameter non-optional as well, so you don't have to force unwrap it to call a function on it.